# Optaplanner : Working with shadow varaibles (custom variable listener)

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am working with a problem that requires to have shadow variables in classes (I used PlanningEntity annotation in these classes) different from the class containing the genuine planning variable. I use VaraibleListener to update those shadow variables (for example : I use one of the shadow variable to just "copy" the content of the genuine planning variable into another class).
And when I run the solver I get "NullPointerException".

Edit : I included a simple example that produced the same problem :

Genuine Variable class :

```
 @PlanningEntity
    public class variable {
    
        @PlanningId
        private Integer id;
        private Integer x;
        
        public variable() {
    
        }   
    
        public variable(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "xRange")
        public Integer getX() {
            return x;
        }
    
   //getters and setters
....
    }
```

Shadow variable class :

```
    @PlanningEntity
    public class yvariable {
        
        private int idy;    
    
        private Integer y;
        
        public yvariable() {
        }
            
    
        @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = yVariableListener.class,
                sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(entityClass = variable.class ,variableName = "x")})
        public Integer getY() {
            return y;
        }
    
        //getters and setters
....
    }
```

Problem fact class :

public class parameter {

```
private int max;
private int min;

public parameter() {

}

public parameter(int max, int min) {
    this.max = max;
    this.min = min;
}
```

//getters and setters
....
}

Planning solution class :

@PlanningSolution
public class Planningsolution {

```
@PlanningEntityProperty
private variable variable;

@ProblemFactProperty
private parameter parameter;

@ProblemFactProperty
private yvariable yvar;

@ValueRangeProvider(id="xRange")
public CountableValueRange<Integer> getxRange(){
    return ValueRangeFactory.createIntValueRange(1, 300);

}

@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score;

public Planningsolution() {

}

public Planningsolution(domain.variable variable, domain.parameter parameter, yvariable yvar) {
    this.variable = variable;
    this.parameter = parameter;
    this.yvar=yvar;
}
```

//getters and setters
....

Variable listener class :

```
public class yVariableListener implements VariableListener<Planningsolution, yvariable> {

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable variable) {
        // Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable variable) {
        //VentesParJour(scoreDirector, variable);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable variable) {
        // Do nothing
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable variable) {
        
        VentesParJour(scoreDirector, variable);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable variable) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable variable) {
        // Do nothing
    }    
    
    protected void VentesParJour(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, yvariable yy) {
        Planningsolution solution = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();

        variable xvar= solution.getVariable();
        
        Integer wtf;
            
        if(xvar.getX()!=null) {
            wtf=xvar.getX();
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(yy, "y");
        yy.setY(wtf);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(yy, "y");

        }
    }       
}
```

Constraint :

maximizing "y" while "x" is less than "max"

I get the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" Exception executing consequence for rule
> "maximum" in domain: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.handleException(DefaultAgenda.java:935)
> at
> org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:460)
> at
> org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:101)
> at
> org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
> at
> org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:748)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:695)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:687)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1090)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1081)
> at
> org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1073)
> at
> org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:70)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.recaller.BestSolutionRecaller.solvingStarted(BestSolutionRecaller.java:50)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:65)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:225)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:192)
> at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:45) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.common.UniRuleContext.lambda$newRuleBuilder$c987a6e2$1(UniRuleContext.java:28)
> at org.drools.model.functions.Block3$Impl.execute(Block3.java:40)   at
> org.drools.modelcompiler.consequence.LambdaConsequence.evaluate(LambdaConsequence.java:74)
> at
> org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:454)
> ... 15 more

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] The question was rewritten, and therefore so is this answer.

The exception in question is:

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception executing consequence for rule "maximum" in domain: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Typically, these exceptions have a cause attached to them, which will point to the code that actually triggered it. (The question does not include full stack trace, and therefore I have no way of knowing.) The only thing that we can infer from this is that there is a constraint called "maximum" and something inside the `.penalize(...)` call threw an exception.

Most likely, it was your match weighter function:

```
.penalize("maximum", ..., (...) -> {
    // something here threw NPE
})
```

If that is the case, then it is your own domain code that throws the exception, and I can not help you. If the root cause of the exception were not in your code, then it is very likely that this would be a bug in OptaPlanner. But so far, nothing I have seen suggests that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact the constraint that throw NPE is :  private Constraint maxValue (ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
          return constraintFactory.forEach(yvariable.class)
            .reward("maximum", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,yvariable::getY);
          }
I'm using the shadow variable "y" which, apparently, doesn't get updated by the VariableListener, because it returns the NPE.